# Taking time to change the orientation in iPad application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, screen-orientation

I am working on one iPad application and its support orientation.but my application taking 4-5 seconds to change the mode. How can I reduce the changing time.Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: Are you using lots of Core Graphics drawing? implementing drawRect? Shadows?

Comment: Yes,its having lots of images.

Comment: I'm not talking about images - specifically implementations of drawRect methods (Core Graphics).